# Extract Word Document Data And Insert Into SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, scripting, ms-word

**Example of Word document**

```
A 1. Name of House: Aasleagh Lodge
Townland: Srahatloe
Near: Killary Harbour, Leenane
Status/Public Access: maintained, private fishing lodge
Date Built: 1838-1850, burnt 1923, rebuilt 1928
Description: Large Victorian country house. Original house 6-bay, 2-storey, 3-bay section on right is higher; after fire house was reduced in size giving current three parallel- hipped roof bays. 
Associated Families: Lord Sligo; rented - Hon David Plunkett ; Capt W.E. and Constance Mary Phillips; James Leslie Wanklyn M.P. for Bradford; Walter H. Maudslay; Ernest Richard Hartley; Alice Marsh, Lord and Lady Brabourne; Western Fisheries Board; Inland Fisheries Ireland.
```

Is there a way of inserting the data that comes after the title e.g. where "Townland" exists in the word document I want the data that comes after it to be inserted into a column in the database, in this case "Srahatloe". I want to extract all this data from the Word document, its for a website that I am building and all the information is stored in the Word document but I need to add the text to the database without copying and pasting because the document is very large (70,000+ words) Is there a script I could use to do this?

**Source Code**

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            var wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\mhoban\Documents\Book.docx");
            var txt = wordDoc.Content.Text;
            var regex = new Regex(@"(Townland\: )(.+?)[\r\n]");
            var allMatches = regex.Matches(txt);
            foreach (Match match in allMatches)
            {
                var townValue = match.Groups[2].Value;

                // Insert values into database
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

                com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Houses (Townland) VALUES (@town)";

                com.Parameters.Add("@town", SqlDbType.NVarChar).SqlValue = townValue;

                com.Connection = con;

                con.Open();

                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Try this http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Load+and+Save+a+Document+to+Database

Comment: Have you tried to use Regex?

Comment: @Pradnya-bolli As i understand he doesn't want to save the whole document but just some text from it. If i am correct you should parse the word document in some way, for example by using Open XML SDK.

Comment: This is not an example of a Word document, it is just two lines of text.
Is there other text surrounding it? Is it in tables or plain paragraphs? Is it always formatted in exactly this way, i.e. "Name: ... Age:..." with a line break in between? soft return or hard return?

Comment: @LocEngineer I have updated the question with the exact word document format all the info is displayed this way

Comment: I think the answer to your question in the other thread using two Split() and a Dictionary sounds best to me. SInce this has escalated from "Name" to "Townland" to "All Fields", Regex might have outgrown its usefulness in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Screams for RegEx. Something like this should get you working:

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(pathToYourDocument);
var txt = wordDoc.Content.Text;
    var regex = new Regex(@"(Townland\: )(.+?)[\r\n]");
    var allMatches = regex.Matches(txt);
    foreach (Match match in allMatches)
    {
        var townValue = match.Groups[2].Value;
        //townValue now holds "Srahatloe"
        //do your magic
    }
```

Comment: how would I access the word document would I need to import it into visual studio or set a path to it?

Comment: Set a reference to Microsoft.Word.Interop (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word). Then create and set variables like the ones I have added to my code above.

Comment: Yes, as I said you need to set a ref to Word.Interop; the full COM assembly name as it appears in the list is "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library"

Comment: var townValue = match.Groups[1].Value; when I put a break point on this line its telling me that townValue holds the value Townland: and not Srahatloe thus inserting Townland: into the database instead

Comment: Arg! Sorry. Forgot it's 1-based. match.Groups[2].Value then.

Comment: its still inserting Townland: I added source code to the question

Comment: with Groups[2]??
Sorry, I don't buy that!

Comment: I just tested this as far as needed. I don't have your db so I doidn't test the actual inserting, but the parameter does hold the correct value (Srahatloe).

Comment: It is working now the database was not refreshing for some reason but its okay now. var regex = new Regex(@"(Townland\: )(.+?)[\r\n]"); how would do this for all the other values in the word document would I just repeat something like this var regex = new Regex(@"(Name of House\: )(.+?)[\r\n]");

Comment: That's what foreach (Match match in allMatches) does. It iterates through all Townland values in your Word document. It should already bew covered sufficiently.

Comment: I mean for the other titles like "Name of House: Aasleagh Lodge" how would implement the regex for that?

Comment: Basically you could simply replace the "Townland" in the regex with any field name you require, the logic stays the same. However you will have to think something through so you do not end up with singular records each only holding one different column value.
Basically You should have enough information to accomplish that now though. Give a little more effort yourself, please.

Comment: would you be able to give me some tips on how to go about this I have been researching and trying different ways of doing it for the last couple of hours but I am having no luck and I am really unsure because I have never worked with Regex before.

Comment: Sorry, commented on the wrong one: I think the answer to your question in the other thread using two Split() and a Dictionary sounds best to me. SInce this has escalated from "Name" to "Townland" to "All Fields", Regex might have outgrown its usefulness in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to extract specific text from word document.

I ended up using regex which is much faster but I don't have the code anymore. Anyway here is how to extract text from word and put it in csv.

Please not you will need PIA installed on your development PC for Office automation.

To add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word go to Visual Studio --> Right Click References-->COM-->Micrososft.Word 14.0 (sorry I do not have access to my work PC so cannot attach screenshots)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string month = "July2014";
        string delimiter = ",";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\temp\\"+ month);
        string[][] csvoutput = new string[][] { };
        csvoutput = new string[][] { new string[]{"School Name","Student Name","Id","ReportDate"}};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, csvoutput[0]));
        File.AppendAllText("C:\\Temp\\"+month+".csv", sb.ToString());

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var id = string.Empty;
            var studentName = string.Empty;
            var school = string.Empty;
            var reportDate = string.Empty;

            if (file.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc"))
            {
                var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                var sourceFile = new FileInfo(file);
                var doc = word.Documents.Open(sourceFile.FullName);
                Console.WriteLine("Processing :-{ " + file.ToLower());

                for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        if (doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.StartsWith("School:"))
                        {
                            school = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString().Replace("\r\a","").Replace("School: ","").Trim();

                        }
                        if (doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.StartsWith("Student Names:"))
                        {
                            studentName = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString().Replace("\r\a", "").Replace("Student Names:","").Trim();

                        }
                        if (doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.StartsWith("xx Id:"))
                        {
                            id = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString().Replace("\r\a", "").Replace("xx Id:", "").Trim();

                        }

                        if (doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.StartsWith("Date of Report:"))
                        {
                            reportDate = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString().Replace("\r\a", "").Replace("Date of Report:","").Trim();

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error occurred" + file.ToLower());
                    }
                }
                csvoutput = new string[][]
                        {
                            new string[]{school,studentName,id,reportDate} 
                        };

                int csvlength = csvoutput.GetLength(0);
                for (int index = 0; index < csvlength; index++)
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, csvoutput[index]));
                File.AppendAllText("C:\\Temp\\" + month + ".csv", sb.ToString());
                word.ActiveDocument.Close();
                word.Quit();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}